# An error when connect python code with Mysql using PyMysql

Tags: python, pymysql

Dears, 
I'm working to connect python code with MysqlDB...
But I get an error when I run the code below

```py
import cursor as cursor
import pymysql.cursors

# Connect to the database
con = pymysql.connect(host='127.0.0.1', user='root', password='123', db='db', port=3306)

request = ('name', 'authorname', 'price', 'file', 'bookcover', 'description')
sql = ("INSERT INTO test" 
       "(Bookname,Author,price,file,Bookcover,about)"
       "VALUES (%s, %s,%s, %s,%s, %s)")
cursor.execute(sql, request)
con.commit()
cursor.close()
con.close()
print('success')
```

```py
/Users/sarahraad/PycharmProjects/untitled2/venv/bin/python /Users/sarahraad/PycharmProjects/untitled2/test1.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/sarahraad/PycharmProjects/untitled2/test1.py", line 5, in <module>
    con = pymysql.connect(host='127.0.0.1', user='root', password='123', db='db', port=3306)
  File "/Users/sarahraad/PycharmProjects/untitled2/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymysql/__init__.py", line 94, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/sarahraad/PycharmProjects/untitled2/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 325, in __init__
    self.connect()
  File "/Users/sarahraad/PycharmProjects/untitled2/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 599, in connect
    self._request_authentication()
  File "/Users/sarahraad/PycharmProjects/untitled2/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 882, in _request_authentication
    auth_packet = _auth.caching_sha2_password_auth(self, auth_packet)
  File "/Users/sarahraad/PycharmProjects/untitled2/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymysql/_auth.py", line 238, in caching_sha2_password_auth
    pkt = conn._read_packet()
  File "/Users/sarahraad/PycharmProjects/untitled2/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 684, in _read_packet
    packet.check_error()
  File "/Users/sarahraad/PycharmProjects/untitled2/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymysql/protocol.py", line 220, in check_error
    err.raise_mysql_exception(self._data)
  File "/Users/sarahraad/PycharmProjects/untitled2/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymysql/err.py", line 109, in raise_mysql_exception
    raise errorclass(errno, errval)
pymysql.err.InternalError: (1049, "Unknown database 'db'")

Process finished with exit code 1
```

plz your advice

Comment: Do you have a database called "db"?

Comment: @PaulCollingwood yes, that’s  what I named it (db)

Comment: The you are not connecting to what you think you are connecting to . The second to last line in your error n otes that pymysql cannot see a database called 'db'. Log into the database using the same credentials you are providing in the code and see if that account can indeed see a databases called db. And given db is the name of the field, it's just confusing to call it db. name your database something other then db.

Answer (score 0):

The error is in this line:

```
con = pymysql.connect(host='127.0.0.1', user='root', password='123', db='db', port=3306)
```

Make sure you state your actual db name and not just "db."

Example:

```
con = pymysql.connect(host='127.0.0.1', user='root', password='123', db='name_of_db', port=3306)`
```

Comment: ''db'' is the name of my database

Comment: Have you tried changing the name of your database or is that even possible?